# JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0x1d200296 in Vitamio Library

Tags: android, mp3, mp4, vitamio, .lrc

I have implemented `Vitamio` Library in my application. Everything work fine but I am facing one issue when user play audio file after video file then application get crashed. In logcat I am getting following error message.

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0x1d200296
```

I have also searched on google then I found this url : https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/143. 
But they are not giving proper solution to solve this issue.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks.